# Why do I get 'arange' is not defined?

Tags: python-2.7

I want to plot a grid from the above code.
But it says that 'arange' is not defined.
Can anyone tell me where's the problem?

```
import numpy  as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
i= 0.033333333
x  = arange(19.933333333,30.066666666,i)
y  = arange(43.400000000,48.533333334,i)
print x
print y
a,b = np.meshgrid(x,y)


plt.plot(a,b,'-oy')
plt.plot(a.transpose(),b.transpose(),'-og')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

From numpy's [docs](https://numpy.org/news/#:%7E:text=NumPy%201.19.0%20release,-Jun%2020%2C%202020&text=This%20is%20the%20first%20release,is%20now%20accessible%20from%20Cython.):

"Jun 20, 2020 – NumPy 1.19.0 is now available. **This is the first release without Python 2 support**, hence it was a “clean-up release”. The minimum supported Python version is now Python 3.6. A"

Try updating to a newer version of Python and see if that fixes the problem.